# Windows 7 shutdown with hidden message box

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, system-shutdown

Windows 7 
simple .bat and .vbs files
level: bloody beginner
summary: suppress windows shutdown message box during "shutdown.exe"-call

I'm trying to run a simple system shutdown that is also clearing my temp files and providing an option to abort. Until now I almost reached my goal using some simple files getting called on after the other.

clear temp data

```
rmdir /s /q "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Temp"
```

execute shutdown

```
c:\windows\system32\shutdown -s -f -t 30
```

then I'm creating a message box allowing me to abort shutdown by pressing the OK-button:

```
x=msgbox ("Temp files cleared. Executing system shutdown now!" & vbNewLine & "Press OK to abort shutdown.",262144+48+0, "System Shutdown")

If x=vbOk Then
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "abortShutdown.bat"
end if
```

(abortShutdown.bat simply is `shutdown /a`)

The system is shutting down properly and the abort works, too. The issue is that Windows 7 is showing me an additional message box saying sth like "Windows will be shut down in less than 1 minute".

As a result I have 2 message boxes on my screen but I only want see my customized box from the .vbs file. At least I managed to move my custom box to the front... I also tried the so-called silent  `WshShell.Run` and `Set WshShell = Nothing` workaround with no success. The message box still keeps popping up.

How can I suppress this box completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a slightly different approach:

```
timeout = 30 'seconds

Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

x = sh.Popup("Temp files cleared. Shutting down in " & timeout & " seconds!" & _
      vbNewLine & "Press OK to shutdown immediately." & vbNewLine & _
      "Press Cancel to abort shutdown.", timeout, "System Shutdown", vbOKCancel)

If x = vbCancel Then
  sh.Run "shutdown -a"
Else
  sh.Run "shutdown -s -f -t 0"
End If
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, this sounds nice. I assume this will call the shutdown after the timeout. So there will be no box because it is shutting down immediately. I get an error (800A000D Type mismatch) when I run your code. Somethings wrong in line 5 char 1.

Comment: @avigrail Sorry, I messed up the order of the last 2 parameters. Fixed.

Comment: Nice, this is much easier and exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again!

Comment: Note: I replaced "vbOKCancel" with "1+256" in my offline version so "Cancel" will be the default button and I can simply press enter to abort.

Comment: @avigrail I'd recommend sticking with the named constants (`vbOKCancel + vbDefaultButton2`) rather than using numeric values, because it makes the code easier to understand.

Comment: I will keep that in mind and totally agree with you. I also changed the first case consequent to `WScript.Quit 0`. Otherwise there will be a command window for about half a second.